# Run batch oracle queries in multiple database

Tags: oracle, batch-file, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have 4 Database connection in SQL developer(oracle). At evening I have to regularly run some scripts in all the 4 connection on same server. Is there is any shortcut that I run script only once and is reflected in all connection which is connected to some DB.

**(NOTE: All the 4 connection will hold exactly same info.)**

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do that: using the command prompt capabilities, not GUI. The only prerequisite is to have SQL*Plus installed on your computer.

For example, create SQL script you're about to run and save it into C:\Temp directory; let's name it "my_script.sql". It can contain both SQL and PL/SQL (don't forget to terminate it with a slash in that case!).

Here's how it should look like:

```
connect &2
spool &1
set echo on
set define off

-- Your SQL statements go here:

select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') vrijeme from dual;

begin
  pkg_payments.p_gimme_my_money;
  commit;
end;
/

-- End of your SQL statements

spool off
exit
```

Then create a DOS batch script, let's name it "run_my_script.bat" and put such a code in there:

```
@echo on
set SCRIPT=C:\Temp\my_script.sql
set SCRIPT_LOG=C:\Temp\my_script

if not exist %SCRIPT% goto END

start sqlplus.exe /nolog @%SCRIPT% %SCRIPT_LOG%.site_1.log "username_1"/"password_1"@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_1_name)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name_1)))
start sqlplus.exe /nolog @%SCRIPT% %SCRIPT_LOG%.site_2.log "username_2"/"password_2"@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_2_name)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name_2)))
start sqlplus.exe /nolog @%SCRIPT% %SCRIPT_LOG%.site_3.log "username_3"/"password_3"@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_3_name)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name_3)))
start sqlplus.exe /nolog @%SCRIPT% %SCRIPT_LOG%.site_4.log "username_4"/"password_4"@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_4_name)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name_4)))

:END
```

As you can see, it

- sets local variables (SCRIPT, which points to a .SQL file you
  created) and SCRIPT_LOG which contains log information about script's
  execution)
- invokes SQL*Plus (in parallel; if you want them to execute
  serially, just remove the START keyword), connecting to each database
  and running the script

The simplest way to test it is to double-click the .BAT file; it'll open 4 "black" command prompt windows and terminate them once the SQL script finishes its job. Check the LOG files!

When you're satisfied with the outcome, schedule .BAT file's execution in Task Scheduler so that they are executed regularly & automatically.

That would be all, I presume.